# list range and length function in python

Tags: python

I have got this error

TypeError: string indices must be integers

I am try to call this function

```
def encrypt():

    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
 

    for i in alphabet:
       
        if i == text[range(len(text)]:
            print(i)

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

encrypt()
```

I have got this error

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

any help plz

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are you trying to accomplish? Also, `text[range[len(text)] ` is missing a parentheses and doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: sorry, I missed that parenthesis, since you changed it for a bracket in your comment

Comment: You can benefit from the Python constant `ascii_lowercase` available in the `string` module, instead of using a custom variable.

`from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(len(text))` is a range function

It was to be an integer in string indices `text[range(len(text)]` not a range function.

Like `text[0]` or `text[1]` , etc,

that's why you are getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I am not sure what exactly are you trying, here is a guess:

```
def encrypt():

    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
 

    for i in alphabet:
        for x in text:
            if i == x:
                print(i)

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

encrypt()
```

Answer (score 1):

`text` is a Python `List` which is itself a `Sequence`.

If you wish to refer an item of this list by its index, you must provide an index number : **an integer**.

Here you are providing a `range` whereas an integer is expected.

```py
type(range(0))  # range
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason has been explained so i just give a code suggestion:

```
import string
def encrypt():
    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
    lowercase_letters = string.ascii_lowercase

    for letter in text:
        if letter in lowercase_letters:
            print(letter)
```